# What is the correct address for precise/12.04 restricted, multiverse and universe ppa?

Tags: 12.04, apt, ppa, official-repositories

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. When I run `sudo apt-get update` now I get the following errors at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't know how long this error has been occurring for, but those repositories seem like ones I want and need to have working, so I'd like to fix it. **What is the correct address (or an alternate) address to use for these repositories?**

**Edit**

The only entries in my `sources.list` file which have the host gb.archive.ubuntu.com (The precise-backports entries do not seem to be failing?):

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

When I navigate to http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/ in my browser I can see the following folders:

- precise-backports
- precise-proposed
- precise-security
- precise-updates
- precise
  -- main
  -- multiverse
  -- restricted
  -- universe

This makes me think the paths changed and so the entries in my `sources.list` are badly formatted now, I'm not sure how to change them to be correct though.

**Edit 2**

The question marked as a duplicate explains how to remove 404'ing repositories, but ***this question explicitly asks what the correct address for precise/12.04 restricted, multiverse and universe ppa is or how to get it**. I am not clear how either is a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Interestingly enough, there are `.gz` and `.bz2` variants of those files on this server. This might actually be a configuration issue, not the wrong `deb` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bare minimum in sources.list is:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse 
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse
```

Edit sources.list using:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can find more alternative using Ubuntu Source List Generator [here](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I used the source list generator here. I initially ticked everything for 12.04, but a large number of the specific repos it generated either timed out or did not have valid public keys (even after downloading their public keys) so ultimately I commented out the medibuntu, gnuzilla, paissad, webupd8team, remastersys, dl.google.com (some), plex.r, packages.mate, virtualbox, yuuguu, lazarus, spotify, fbreader, hydr0g3n repos - but now I can update/upgrade everyting. Thanks!